# My $scope.variable is changing but it's not coming up on HTML ($scope.$apply)

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
var meme = angular.module('testApp');
meme.controller('awsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myDate = 'Hello there!';
    $scope.testSend1Response = '';
    //-----
    //--set up configuration for AWS
    //-----
    var credentials = new AWS.Credentials('AKIAI4UYCXVJ2FJICSHA', 'Sj42vmNla34trodyrvIcVIkbo+mczVo5QMIlfVHg');
    AWS.config.region = "ap-southeast-2";
    AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //--send message
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $scope.testSend1 = function() {
      var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
      var params = {
         DelaySeconds: 10,
         MessageAttributes: {
          "Title": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "The Whistler"
           },

          "Author": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: "John Grisham"
           },

          "WeeksOn": {
            DataType: "Number",
            StringValue: "6"
           }
         },

         MessageBody: "Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 12/11/2016.",

         QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/448283262740/reporting'

        };

      sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          $scope.testSend1Response = '  Success.  MessageId: ' + data.MessageId; // << THE PROBLEM IS HERE
          console.log("Success", $scope.testSend1Response);
          console.log('Success2 ' + data.MessageId);
        }
      });
    }
  }]);
```

In this area:

```
      sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          $scope.testSend1Response = '  Success.  MessageId: ' + data.MessageId; // << THE PROBLEM IS HERE
          console.log("Success", $scope.testSend1Response);
          console.log('Success2 ' + data.MessageId);
        }
      });
```

I am using AWS sqs to send a message then log that it has been sent and assign the scope variable `testSend1Response` the MessageId.

In my HTML I have:

```
<button ng-click="testSend1()"> Send data </button>
<span> Response: {{testSend1Response}}</span>
```

When I click on the button, the response doesn't get printed in HTML where I'm expecting it to get printed, but in the console log I can see a MessageId of say `1aacc`, when I click on the button a second time, `1aacc` gets printed in HTML but in the console log I can see a MessageId of `2bbdd`, so it seems that the `$scope.testSend1Response` is behind the log and is showing me the previous MessageId instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because Angular hasn't "digested" this change, what that means is that Angular didn't know that this variable would change in that area so by the time the function has finished running Angular has finished its digestion loop and now the scope variable `$scope.testSend1Response` is set but Angular doesn't know about it or didn't recognise it.

The same thing would happen if you change a scope variable inside a javascript timeout function.
Asynchronous Angular services however, such as `$http` are wrapped and being digested by angular by default.

The way to fix that issue is to wrap that variable in an `$apply` function like so:

```
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.testSend1Response = '  Success.  MessageId: ' + data.MessageId;
      });
      console.log("Success", $scope.testSend1Response);
      console.log('Success2 ' + data.MessageId);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Checkout this amazing Post by Jim Hoskins for more info:
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html